# Can't step in GDB past Thumb/ARM transition, ARM breakpoints are not set

Tags: linux, debugging, android-ndk, gdb, arm

I'm debugging a program with no symbols on Android 1.6 emulator. There's a crash (signal) during loading of a SO library, I'm trying to track it down. The crash is somewhere in the library startup code, I know that much. I know a safe location in the SO loader code before control goes from loader to the SO. I can set a breakpoint there, and step all the way to the BLX into the library. The loader's code is Thumb. The library startup code is ARM.

Since there are no symbols, I use `set arm force-mode xxx` to let GDB know. Before I initiate the sequence that leads to stopping in the loader, I set the mode to Thumb.

The problem is, though, is that when I come to the `BLX` instruction and try to single-step (`si`), the debugger does not stop at the next instruction - it goes all the way to the signal. Even if I do a `set arm force-mode arm` before executing the `si` on the BLX, it does not seem to matter.

Setting a breakpoint in the library startup code doesn't help either. I'm not sure how exactly does GDB set breakpoints, but it looks like the mismatch between the currently executing code's mode and the intended breakpoint target mode is a hindrance.

EDIT: I've even tried monkey-patching the running code to have a BKPT command at the right place - GDB still does not break.

EDIT2: monkey patching the code section does not work, it seems. I can use a part of the data section as a scratch area though. Still, BKPT does not cause the GDB to break...

---

EDIT3: using a scratch data area for a three line code snippet, I can switch out of Thumb and come back into GDB in a signal. HOWEVER, now that I'm in ARM mode, GDB has trouble setting breakpoints for some reason.

The BLX into library command goes like this: `blx r2`. r2 has the value of 0x80601b60 - that's the library startup routine.

When I'm stopped on BLX, here's what I do. I have a scratch area in the data section. I place the following ARM commands there:

```
mov r12, 0 ; the value of r12 will be soon ruined by the code anyway
ldr r12, [r12] ; Provoke a SIGSEGV to stop GDB in ARM mode
mov pc, r2 ; To resume back into the library
```

Then I forcibly set the value of r2 to my scratch area, set the GDB mode to ARM and continue. A SIGSEGV in the scratch area is naturally thrown.

Here I am, in the ARM mode (both CPU and GDB's force-mode). I set a breakpoint at 0x80601b60 - the library entry point. I change the value of r2 back to 0x80601b60 so that the third command jumps there. I change the value of r12 to a valid-to-read address so that the signal is not rethrown on retry. And I issue a `signal 0` command to continue without a signal.

I'm expecting that control would go to 0x80601b60 and a breakpoint would be hit. It's not. Why not? Is the `mov` semantics different when assigning to pc by any chance (like the `ldr rx, [pc]` is)?

Setting the breakpoint on the `mov pc, r2` doesn't work either. Is there a problem with setting breakpoints in GDB while in stopped by signal mode? But it does not work even if I set the breakpoint before the signal (while in Thumb mode).

Stranger yet, I'm encountering the case when control goes past the `mov pc, r2` as if it's not executed at all. But the previous instruction *is* executed once I fix r12.

Is there a single-step analogue to `signal 0`?

Comment: Try `set arm force-mode auto` and `set arm fallback-mode auto`.  This should examine the CPSR.  The issue with the BLX is that often `GDB` will put an `illegal` instruction at the next execution point to single step.  If it is confused about modes, then it might write an `illegal` ARM vs Thumb instruction.  Patching code is problematic due to ICACHE/DCACHE, etc.  I don't know what monkey-patch means, but you need to follow a SMC procedure. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code

Comment: Nah, still falls through :(

Comment: It is indeed, but so is every code section on Android. Marked as `r-xp` in `maps`.

Comment: Can you "manually emulate" the BLX instruction by writing to PC/LR/CPSR and then telling GCC it's in ARM mode?

Comment: No, does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in GDB.  I am preparing a fix now.  See 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56962

[edited; initially, I had linked to the wrong URL, above, as explained in my reply below.  Now the URL above is correct.]

You can either cherry-pick my gerrit submission, or wait for Google to release an updated NDK.  Or if you are using Linux or Windows on x86, I could possibly share a binary.

Gerrit submission is: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/61322/

Comment: I apologize for taking so long with this.  In fact, the bug report I listed above is for a slightly different issue-- step instead of stepi-- and has a different cause.  I will supply a different answer below with my solution to your actual question.

Comment: I'm accepting, but I didn't try the patch - the underlying issue that I was trying to debug in the first place was resolved by other means.

Comment: Meanwhile, the similar problem remains in GDB 8.1 (you can step, but you can't set thumb breakpoints), yet it's fixed in GDB 8.3. JFYI. They seem to break and fix it again and again...